# Leer una función por teclado y graficarla en matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo un programa donde quiero leer una función a través de una caja de texto y mostrarla en la gráfica.
Cuando ingreso una función del tipo "f(x)=x^2-9", se grafica sin problemas, pero cuando intento graficar "f(x)=x^2-9x-81", me lanza los siguientes errores:

```
Error using symengine
Unexpected 'identifier'.

Error in sym>convertExpression (line 1588)
s = mupadmex({x});

Error in sym>convertChar (line 1486)
    s = convertExpression(x);

Error in sym>tomupad (line 1236)
        S = convertChar(x);

Error in sym (line 215)
                S.s = tomupad(x);

Error in sym/subs (line 57)
if ~isa(F,'sym'), F = sym(F); end

Error in Biseccion_GUI>fn_Callback (line 93)
plot(dominio,subs(fn,x,dominio),dominio,subs(0,x,dominio));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Biseccion_GUI (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)Biseccion_GUI('fn_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.
```

Aqui pongo el código donde leo la función y grafico.

```
function fn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to fn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of fn as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of fn as a double
cla reset;
syms x
fn=get(hObject,'String');
axes(handles.grafica);
mini=str2double(get(handles.domMin,'String'));
maxi=str2double(get(handles.domMax,'String'));
dominio=mini:0.01:maxi;
grid on;
hold on;
plot(dominio,subs(fn,x,dominio),dominio,subs(0,x,dominio));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el error estaba en como ingresaba la función por teclado, matlab no reconoce esto "9x" como un número multiplicando a una variable, se debe ingresar como "9*x".